How to consolidate multiple lines in a list using a common string?
My office network csv sample file is as below. The file contains data of network interfaces, however the data is scattered across three lines in the list for any given interface (for example 'pe_node1_ge-1/2/2.20' got three lines of data).
I am trying to consolidate these into a single line without changing the number of columns (0 to 15). Any help is greatly appreciated.
lines_list:
[Oct_04_09:19:08, PE_INT_DESC, pe_node1_ge-1/2/2.20, TO_PE3, up_up, , , , , , , , , , , WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier

Oct_04_09:19:09, PE_IPV4_ADDRESS, pe_node1_ge-1/2/2.20, , , , 192.168.20.2/24, 192.168.20.1, vrrp-group_1, , , , , , , WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier

Oct_04_09:19:18, PE_ROUTING_VRRP, pe_node1_ge-1/2/2.20, , , , , , , , master, 192.168.20.2, vr-uptime:14w2d11:30_mr-uptime:14w2d10:31__, VRRP, , WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier

Oct_04_09:19:19, PE_INT_DESC, pe_node2_ge-1/1/1.10, TO_PE2, up_up, , , , , , , , , , , WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier

Oct_04_09:19:20, PE_IPV4_ADDRESS, pe_node2_ge-1/1/1.10, , , , 192.168.10.2/24, 192.168.10.1, vrrp-group_1, , , , , , , WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier

Oct_04_09:19:28, PE_ROUTING_VRRP, pe_node2_ge-1/1/1.10, , , , , , , , master, 192.168.10.2, vr-uptime:13w1d11:30_mr-uptime:15w2d10:31__, VRRP, , WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier]

Expected List:
[Oct_04_09:19:08, PE_INT, pe_node1_ge-1/2/2.20, TO_PE3, up_up, , 192.168.20.2/24, 192.168.20.1, vrrp-group_1, , master, 192.168.20.2, vr-uptime:14w2d11:30_mr-uptime:14w2d10:31__, VRRP, , WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier

Oct_04_09:19:19, PE_INT, pe_node1_ge-1/1/1.10, TO_PE2, up_up, , 192.168.10.2/24, 192.168.10.1, vrrp-group_1, , master, 192.168.10.2, vr-uptime:13w1d11:30_mr-uptime:15w2d10:31__, VRRP, , WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier]


Does the CSV file really have [ and ] characters on some of the lines? Why?

The first two fields are different on each line? How do you decide which should be in the result?

Anyway, make a dictionary that uses the pe_node field as the keys. Then you can loop through the file and merge the rest of the fields.

@Barmar, Thanks for the questions. The whole csv was generated as a single list, that's why you see '[' at the start and ']' at the end. I prefer to retain the values on the line "PE_INT_DESC" for the first two fields.


"without changing the number of columns (0 to 15)"
There are only 15 columns in you file, and 0 to 15 will mean 16 columns, so I assume you mean 15 columns.

Importing a CSV, and grouping it using Pandas, is a subject covered multiple times on stackoverflow.com, or explained in the docs.
import pandas

cols = ['col0','col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9','col10','col11','col12','col13','col14']
x =pandas.read_csv('lines_list', sep=',', names=cols)

print(x)
print(x.groupby('col1').max())

output:




col0
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
col6
col7
col8
col9
col10
col11
col12
col13
col14




[Oct_04_09:19:08
PE_INT_DESC
pe_node1_ge-1/2/2.20
TO_PE3
up_up










WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier


Oct_04_09:19:09
PE_IPV4_ADDRESS
pe_node1_ge-1/2/2.20



192.168.20.2/24
192.168.20.1
vrrp-group_1






WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier


Oct_04_09:19:18
PE_ROUTING_VRRP
pe_node1_ge-1/2/2.20







master
192.168.20.2
vr-uptime:14w2d11:30_mr-uptime:14w2d10:31__
VRRP

WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier


Oct_04_09:19:19
PE_INT_DESC
pe_node2_ge-1/1/1.10
TO_PE2
up_up










WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier


Oct_04_09:19:20
PE_IPV4_ADDRESS
pe_node2_ge-1/1/1.10



192.168.10.2/24
192.168.10.1
vrrp-group_1






WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier


Oct_04_09:19:28
PE_ROUTING_VRRP
pe_node2_ge-1/1/1.10







master
192.168.10.2
vr-uptime:13w1d11:30_mr-uptime:15w2d10:31__
VRRP

WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier]







col0
col2
col3
col4
col5
col6
col7
col8
col9
col10
col11
col12
col13
col14




col1
















pe_node1_ge-1/2/2.20
PE_ROUTING_VRRP
TO_PE3
up_up

192.168.20.2/24
192.168.20.1
vrrp-group_1

master
192.168.20.2
vr-uptime:14w2d11:30_mr-uptime:14w2d10:31__
VRRP

WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier


pe_node2_ge-1/1/1.10
PE_ROUTING_VRRP
TO_PE2
up_up

192.168.10.2/24
192.168.10.1
vrrp-group_1

master
192.168.10.2
vr-uptime:13w1d11:30_mr-uptime:15w2d10:31__
VRRP

WA_WE_PI_960_B_Pier]



